# T-SQL - using GROUP BY GROUPING SET - Filter single set

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, grouping-sets

in this statement

```
from 
    #base U     
    group by grouping sets 
    (
     (a,b,c,d)  --1
    ,(a,b,c,d,e,f) --2 
    ,(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) --3
    )
```

is possibile in a single  set  an filter  before aggregation ?

`(a,b,c,d,e,f) where b <> 0`

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be to put the (a,b,c,d,e,f) grouping with a filter as as a seperate query and then use UNION to merge the results.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try it .

```
select ... 
from #base U     
group by grouping sets 
((a,b,c,d), (a,b,c,d,e,f,g)) 
union all 
select ... 
from #base U
where b<>0     
group by a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Hope it can help you.

Best Regards,

Rachel